# JavaScript Form validation using isNaN or Type is not working

Tags: javascript

I tried to validate user input whether user input is a number or string by using isNaN or Type but it is not working. I wrote the if statement inside my function to validate user inputs. I want to user to prompt a number only, not a string. If user input is a string, I would like to pop up an alert to the user.

Can anyone can spot any mistake on my code? Either I put the code incorrectly or I missed something.

```js
function updateTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
    var values = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        values.push(parseFloat(list[i].value));
    }

    total = values.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
        return previousValue + currentValue;
    });

    if (isNaN(list)) {
        alert("Error on input");
    }

    avgMarks = total / 5;

    document.getElementById("total").value = total;
    document.getElementById("display").value = avgMarks;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ordering form</title>


</head>

<body>
    <h1>Get marks</h1>
    <div>
        <form id="form" method="post">
            <label for="marks">Enter your 5 marks: </label><br>

            <p>Mark 1</p>
            <input type="text"  class='input' value="0" onchange='updateTotal();'><br>
            <p>Mark 2</p>
            <input type="text"  class='input' value="0" onchange='updateTotal();'><br>
            <p>Mark 2</p>
            <input type="text"  class='input' value="0" onchange='updateTotal();'><br>
            <p>Mark 4</p>
            <input type="text"  class='input' value="0" onchange='updateTotal();'><br>
            <p>Mark 5</p>
            <input type="text"  class='input' value="0" onchange='updateTotal();'><br>
            <p>Total 5 marks : </p>
            <input type="text" name="totalMarks" id="total" value=""><br>
            <p>The average of your marks is : </p>
            <input type="text" name="avgMarks" id="display" value="">
            <br>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!--JavaScript-->
    <script src="debug1_with_error.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if (isNaN(list))` the `NodeList` of elements is always going to be a `NaN`, since it's a `NodeList`.

Comment: You need to add `isNaN(list[i].value)` inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `list` is a `NodeList` of elements, not what you want to test. The values you want to test are each individual value, one at a time, in your `values` array, or just `isNaN(total)`, because `NaN` would come through in the total if any one value were `NaN`.